# How to merge two xarray.Datasets based on common coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to merge two `xarray.Dataset`-objects.

My code looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

N_CHAINS = 4
N_DRAWS = 1000
N_PLAYERS = 5

player_idx = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 2]
opponent_idx = [0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3]

h2h_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    tuple(zip(player_idx, opponent_idx)), names=('player_id', 'opponent_id')
)

obs = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        n_points_won=(['h2h_id'], np.array([11, 11, 8, 9, 4, 11, 7, 11, 11, 11])),
        n_points_lost=(['h2h_id'], np.array([9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 1, 11, 2, 3, 6])),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        h2h_id=(['h2h_id'], h2h_idx),
    )
)

alpha = np.random.rand(N_CHAINS, N_DRAWS, N_PLAYERS, N_PLAYERS) * 100
beta = np.random.rand(N_CHAINS, N_DRAWS, N_PLAYERS, N_PLAYERS) * 100

pos = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        alpha=(['chain', 'draw', 'player_id', 'opponent_id'], alpha),
        beta=(['chain', 'draw', 'player_id', 'opponent_id'], beta),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        chain=(['chain'], list(range(N_CHAINS))),
        draw=(['draw'], list(range(N_DRAWS))),
        player_id=(['player_id'], list(range(N_PLAYERS))),
        oppponent_id=(['opponent_id'], list(range(N_PLAYERS))),
    ),
)
 

combined = xr.combine_nested([obs, pos], concat_dim=['player_id', 'opponent_id']) # this results in an error
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: concat_dims has length 2 but the datasets passed are
> nested in a 1-dimensional structure

How can I merge the two datasets?
The goal is to create a `xarray.Dataset` with coordinates `h2h_id`, `player_id`, `opponent_id`, `chain` and `draw`. Basically for each data variable in `obs` I want to concat the corresponding `alpha`- and `beta` values from pos of that particular observation (through `player_id` and `opponent_id`)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's way to merge the two datasets first and then concatenate the alpha and beta values correspondently:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

N_CHAINS = 4
N_DRAWS = 1000
N_PLAYERS = 5

player_idx = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 2]
opponent_idx = [0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3]

h2h_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    tuple(zip(player_idx, opponent_idx)), names=('player_id', 'opponent_id')
)

obs = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        n_points_won=(['h2h_id'], np.array([11, 11, 8, 9, 4, 11, 7, 11, 11, 11])),
        n_points_lost=(['h2h_id'], np.array([9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 1, 11, 2, 3, 6])),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        h2h_id=(['h2h_id'], h2h_idx),
    )
)

alpha = np.random.rand(N_CHAINS, N_DRAWS, N_PLAYERS, N_PLAYERS) * 100
beta = np.random.rand(N_CHAINS, N_DRAWS, N_PLAYERS, N_PLAYERS) * 100

pos = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        alpha=(['chain', 'draw', 'player_id', 'opponent_id'], alpha),
        beta=(['chain', 'draw', 'player_id', 'opponent_id'], beta),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        chain=(['chain'], list(range(N_CHAINS))),
        draw=(['draw'], list(range(N_DRAWS))),
        player_id=(['player_id'], list(range(N_PLAYERS))),
        opponent_id=(['opponent_id'], list(range(N_PLAYERS))), 
    ),
)

# Resetting indexes of the datasets
obs_reset = obs.reset_index('h2h_id')
pos_reset = pos.reset_index(['chain', 'draw', 'player_id', 'opponent_id'])

# Merging the datasets
merged = xr.merge([obs_reset, pos_reset], combine_attrs='override', compat='override')

# Extracting alpha and beta values corresponding to 'player_id' and 'opponent_id'
alpha_values = merged['alpha'].sel(player_id=merged['player_id'], opponent_id=merged['opponent_id'])
beta_values = merged['beta'].sel(player_id=merged['player_id'], opponent_id=merged['opponent_id'])

# Concatenating alpha and beta values along a new dimension
concatenated_values = xr.concat([alpha_values, beta_values], dim='concat_dim')

# Assigning the concatenated values to a new variable in the obs dataset
merged['alpha_beta_concat'] = concatenated_values

# Show the updated merged dataset
print(merged)
```

Output:

```
 <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (h2h_id: 10, chain: 4, draw: 1000, player_id: 5,
                        opponent_id: 5, concat_dim: 2)
Coordinates:
    player_id          (h2h_id) int64 1 1 2 3 4 4 0 0 2 2
    opponent_id        (h2h_id) int64 0 3 1 4 1 1 1 4 3 3
  * chain              (chain) int64 0 1 2 3
  * draw               (draw) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 994 995 996 997 998 999
Dimensions without coordinates: h2h_id, concat_dim
Data variables:
    n_points_won       (h2h_id) int64 11 11 8 9 4 11 7 11 11 11
    n_points_lost      (h2h_id) int64 9 9 11 11 11 1 11 2 3 6
    alpha              (chain, draw, player_id, opponent_id) float64 75.88 .....
    beta               (chain, draw, player_id, opponent_id) float64 2.447 .....
    alpha_beta_concat  (concat_dim, chain, draw, h2h_id) float64 87.48 ... 88.44
```